# Which method is better for array Declaration in terms of time and space complexity?

Tags: arrays, pointers

I declared the Array in two ways.I want to know which one is better in terms of time and space complexity?

1 .int foo[3] = { 10, 20, 30 };
2. int foo[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
  OR
1. char *arr[3]={"Anil","Sunil","Rohit"};
2. char *arr[]={"Anil","Sunil","Rohit"};

Comment: I am comparing int foo[3] = { 10, 20, 30 }; and int foo[] = { 10, 20, 30 }

Comment: Or  I am comparing char *arr[3]={"Anil","Sunil","Rohit"}; and char *arr[]={"Anil","Sunil","Rohit"};

Answer (score 0):

The C/C++ standards do not define this. It is up to the compiler implementors which of the two, if any, is faster. In all likelihood, a modern compiler will treat those two choices as equal, respectively.

I think the issue of efficiency only arises, when the array in question will be too large for the programmer to explicitly type in all the initial values. For example, if you'd initialise an array with all the same values, you could consider `memset(foo, -1, SIZE)`, where -1 is your value, and SIZE the number of entries of foo.